# Python 2.7/OpenCV 3.0: Major error in 3D points of an object calculating using cv2.triangulatePoints

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, 3d, triangulation

I wrote code in Python 2.7 using OpenCV 3.0 to find out 3D points of an object. I created three python scripts (*traingulate, centroid_cal and rectify_img* ) out of which two are function scripts (*centroid_cal and rectify_img with function centroid and rectify*).  The sequence I followed:

- calibrated the stereo camera and save the cameraMatrixL, distCoeffsL, cameraMatrixR, distCoeffsR, R, T where R and T are rotation and translation matrices. The calibarted error was less than *0.03 pixels* for both cameras.
- capture left and right images using calibrated cameras and used *cv2.stereoRectify* to rectified the images. I got *R1,R2,P1,P2,Q,validPixROI1, validPixROI2* using *cv2.stereoRectify*. `R1,R2,P1,P2,Q,validPixROI1, validPixROI2 = cv2.stereoRectify(cameraMatrixL,distCoeffsL,cameraMatrixR,distCoeffsR,(640,480),R,T,alpha=0)`
- Then I undistort the images:
  `mapxL, mapyL = cv2.initUndistortRectifyMap(cameraMatrixL, distCoeffsL, R1, P1, (640,480), cv2.CV_32FC1)
  mapxR, mapyR = cv2.initUndistortRectifyMap(cameraMatrixR, distCoeffsR, R2, P2, (640,480), cv2.CV_32FC1)
  left_image = cv2.remap(left_image_undist, mapxL, mapyL,cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
  right_image = cv2.remap(right_image_undist, mapxR, mapyR,cv2.INTER_LINEAR)`
- Finding out corresponding points in left and right images using *centroid_cal* script.
- Use *cv2.triangulatePoints* to find out 3D points.

Full codes for each script is given below:

Code for ***triangulate script***

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from rectify_img import rectify
from centroid_cal import centroid_cal

left_image_undist = cv2.imread('left150.png')
right_image_undist = cv2.imread('right150.png')
left_image,right_image,P1,P2 = rectify(left_image_undist,right_image_undist)
left_points = centroid_cal(left_image)
right_points = centroid_cal(right_image)
points = cv2.triangulatePoints(P1,P2,left_points,right_points)
points /= points[3]
print points
```

Code for ***rectify_img***

```
def rectify(left_image_undist,right_image_undist):
    import numpy as np
    import cv2
    cameraMatrixL = np.load('mtx_Left.npy')
    distCoeffsL = np.load('dist_Left.npy')
    cameraMatrixR = np.load('mtx_Right.npy')
    distCoeffsR = np.load('dist_Right.npy')
    R = np.load('R.npy')
    T = np.load('T.npy')
    R1,R2,P1,P2,Q,validPixROI1, validPixROI2 = cv2.stereoRectify(cameraMatrixL,distCoeffsL,cameraMatrixR,distCoeffsR,(640,480),R,T,alpha=0)
    #computes undistort and rectify maps
    mapxL, mapyL = cv2.initUndistortRectifyMap(cameraMatrixL, distCoeffsL, R1, P1, (640,480), cv2.CV_32FC1)
    mapxR, mapyR = cv2.initUndistortRectifyMap(cameraMatrixR, distCoeffsR, R2, P2, (640,480), cv2.CV_32FC1)
    left_image = cv2.remap(left_image_undist, mapxL, mapyL,cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
    right_image = cv2.remap(right_image_undist, mapxR, mapyR,cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
    return left_image,right_image,P1,P2
```

Code for ***centroid_cal*** (*I detected white color*):

```
def centroid_cal(image):
    lower_white = np.array([100,100,100], dtype=np.uint8)
    upper_white = np.array([255,255,255], dtype=np.uint8)
    bin_img_pts = cv2.inRange(image, lower_white, upper_white)
    #cv2.imshow('res',binimg)
    bin_img_pts[bin_img_pts!=0] = 255
    # flood fill background to find inner holes
    holes_in_pts = bin_img_pts.copy()
    retval, image, mask, rect = cv2.floodFill(holes_in_pts, None, (0, 0), 255)
    # invert holes mask, bitwise or with img fill in holes
    holes_in_pts_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(holes_in_pts)
    #cv2.imshow('holes',holes)
    filled_holes_pts = cv2.bitwise_or(bin_img_pts, holes_in_pts_inv)
    #cv2.imshow('filled holes', filled_holes_pts)
    _pts_img_label = morphology.label(filled_holes_pts)
    #cv2.imshow('label',_pts_img_label)
    cleaned_pts_img = morphology.remove_small_objects(_pts_img_label, min_size=1264, connectivity=4)
    #cv2.imshow('clea',cleaned_pts_img)
    img_unlabel_pts = np.zeros((_pts_img_label.shape))
    img_unlabel_pts[cleaned_pts_img > 0] = 255
    img_unlabel_pts = np.uint8(img_unlabel_pts)
    #### here conversion of array into uint8 data conversion is important
    ### else cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats will show error.
    nb_components, output, stats_pts, centroids_pts = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(img_unlabel_pts, connectivity=4)
    #cv2.imshow("centroid", img3)
    centroids_pts = centroids_pts[np.where(stats_pts[:, -1] > 1000)]
    centroids_pts = centroids_pts[1:nb_components]
    req_points = centroids_pts[1,:]
    #print(_pts_points)
    return req_points
```

The answer I got is (mm units):

```
    [[ -74.75449128]
 [ -32.9271306 ]
 [ 320.21282459]
 [   1.0        ]]
```

while it should be nearly

```
    [[ -55.00 ]
     [ -50.00]
     [ 340.00]
     [   1.0        ]]
```

I wants to know how to correct these errors? Where am I doing wrong?

All matrices I'm posting here too for reference.

```
cameraMatrixL = np.array(
    [[ 534.40241484,    0.        ,  298.51610503],
     [   0.        ,  527.62465955,  214.45395059],
     [   0.        ,    0.        ,    1.        ]])

distCoeffsL = np.array([[ 0.05192082, -0.0262804 , -0.00407178, -0.00618521, -0.22427776]])

cameraMatrixR = np.array(
    [[ 540.33748563,    0.        ,  304.35042046],
     [   0.        ,  534.67506784,  218.16718612],
     [   0.        ,    0.        ,    1.        ]])

distCoeffsR = np.array([[ 0.0386014 ,  0.34514765, -0.00434087, -0.00734639, -2.09991534]])

R = np.array(
    [[ 0.99959407, -0.02457877,  0.01440768],
     [ 0.02455863,  0.99969715,  0.00157338],
     [-0.01444199, -0.00121891,  0.99989497]])

T = np.array(
    [[-94.95904357],
     [ -0.849498  ],
     [  7.4674219 ]])
```

I am uploading my images and all matrices if anyone needs.

Link to google drive in which files are kept. [LINK](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1OfBSXX5PMVNxvIMtVJcg2nKt0Y48TN4Q?usp=sharing)

I am adding Images also: 
[image]
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Dropbox don't provide service in my country. Can you change to google / microsoft driver ?

Comment: Can you provide the files in plain text instead of numpy binary?  it is more complicated to download, load them on  numpy and analyze instead of doing it right away

Comment: Hello, @Silencer thanks for the comment. I add a link to google drive. Please see the edited question.

Comment: Hello, @api55 thanks for the comment. I added images as well matrices in question. I pasted new link to google drive too. Please check the edited question.

Comment: @NaseebGill I want to to know what  your `centroid_cal()` does. You fine the white regions, enclosed them, and remove small objects, then there must exist no less than three regions. So which center do you want? How do you make sure the calculated center is your want? Why do you think it it should be some value else? Have you plot the `req_points`, are them right?

Comment: @Silencer, I calculated centroids of white objects using `centroid_cal()`. Offcourse number of centroids are three in number. I don't know yet how to process all centroids simultaneously. So, I picked 2nd centroid using `req_points = centroids_pts[1,:]` and use it to calculate 3D points, just to check accuracy of code. In images, used centroid is far left one. In matlab, I check centroid and nearly they are same. I don't know how to plot `req_points`. For far left object centroids are: left_points = `[ 248.08  179.33]` right_points = `[  57.60  182.38]`

Comment: @NaseebGill Ok, I see, you just select the second center of the detected to do the process. Maybe the region is not corresponding(I guess).  I'll test

Comment: @NaseebGill Unfortunately, the centroids you selected are corresponding, then i don't know where goes wrong. If you choose the first centroids, the result becomes even worse , `[[40.13491827], [ -87.91308119],[ 375.00901087],[1.]]` . Maybe the centroids are not that precisious for calculating that.. I'm not good at multiview geometry.

Comment: @Silencer, for 1st centroid output is `[[  40.13] [ -87.913]  [ 375.00]  [ 1.     ]]` while measured values are nearly `[[  70] [ -100]  [ 350.00]  [ 1.     ]]`. So every time error is nearly in same range. So I think I made some error in using correct `flags` or I missed some step. These errors are major so I can't avoid these too. Anyway, thanks for your time.

Comment: @NaseebGill So, should they be the same, I'm not really understand.

Comment: @Silencer, for your_Maybe the centroids are not that precious for calculating that._ Sir in Matlab I follow same steps and I got very accurate results. But I want to do the same thing in Python.